# How to work out the unknown vertex of a parallelogram given the other three

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have changed the numbers so you're not giving me the answers.

Let A (1, 1), B (5,2), C (2, 4) and D (x, y) be the vertices of a parallelogram ABCD.

What are the coordinates of vertex D?

-As I am struggling on how to do this, I would appreciate it if you could show me an example of how to do it? Using my random numbers or your own?

Comment: I get to Cross-multiplying, and get confused: http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Parallelograms/Parallelograms.faq.question.251045.html

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We know the diagonals of parallelogram with vertices $(x_i,y_i)$ (where $i=1,2,3,4$ in order) bisect each other ([proof](http://www.sonoma.edu/users/w/wilsonst/courses/math_150/theorems/Parallelograms/T3.html))

$$\implies\frac{x_1+x_3}2=\frac{x_2+x_4}2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\vec{BD}= \vec{BC}+\vec{CD}= \vec{BC}+\vec{BA}$$

**added**

You get

$$(x-5,y-2)=(-3,2)+(-4,-1)$$

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but I'm not sure how to do this as I don't know what D is?

Comment: @Dave You can calculate $\vec{BC}+\vec{BA}$. Then use the fact that $\vec{BD}=(x-5,y-2)$